# Using Service Account (Protected by Private Key) to call Spring Service in Google Cloud

Tags: spring, rest, client, private-key, google-cloud-platform

I am kind of new to Google Cloud Platform.
I have deployed my Spring REST Services.
I am able to call the REST services them from a browser.

These services needs to be accessed only by a Service Account, and the access needs to be secured by the API Private Key.

Is there any sample code to do this?

```
String resourceURL = "lucky-curve-175103.appspot.com/myService?input={s1}";  
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
String testValue = "098-98-0987"; 
CwResult cwResult = restTemplate.getForObject(resourceURL, CwResult.class, testValue ); 
System.out.println("Result " + cwResult.getResult());
```

This code works and I get the Result printed on the console.
How do I make this call using the service account and privatekey ?

Comment: Hi. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code  or whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: String resourceURL = "https://lucky-curve-175103.appspot.com/myService?input={s1}";   
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
String testValue = "098-98-0987";   
CwResult cwResult = restTemplate.getForObject(resourceURL, CwResult.class, testValue );    
System.out.println("Result " + cwResult.getResult());     ---> This code works and I get the Result printed on the console. How do i make this call using the service account and privatekey.